# Ambiguous reference to b2FilterData

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

When I write this code below:

```
var mWorld:b2World = new b2World(gravity, false);
```

Why am I getting this error "Ambiguous reference to b2FilterData"?

Comment: The error indicates there are two classes named "b2FilterData" in context, so a reference needs to be fully qualified (ex "com.abc.b2FilterData") to disambiguate which class is being referred to.

Comment: there are two classes named b2filterdata and i dont know which one box2d wants to use. And thanks for reply

Comment: actually it uses namespace called b2internal

Comment: its working i dont know what happened but now there is one b2filterdata file ahah its really interesting